# x86 error while installing rhel6(x86-64) on virtual box

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

i have a computer with the following configuration
:
pentium dual core ||||| 2.50ghz|||||      1.75 gb ram |||||     windows xp(sp2)(x86)
i installed oracle virtual box and on turning on the virtual machine the rhel 6 booting screen displays but when it starts automatic booting i get the error:
**this kernel requires an x86-64 cpu but only detected an i686 cpu

unable to boot please use a kernel appropriate to your cpu**
i am running a 32 bit processor then why the error?please help me solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x86_64 variant requires a 64-bit processor that supports AMD64 or Intel64. You do not have one.

Comment: thank you for the answer.one doubt:why is it named as x86-64?when it doesnt support 32 bit?

Comment: Did you think that the "64" stood for "32"? NO. IT DOESN'T.

Comment: X86 stands for 32 isnt it?

Comment: @ragsvds the x86-64 is both a 64 bit chip, *and* can do 32 bit for backwards compatibility. In fact most OSes that run on x86-64 can have a mix of 32 bit code and 64 bit code running within the same OS (as long as you have the libraries). The kernel tends to be 64 bit tho.

Comment: @RichHomolka thanks a lot..can you suggest what i can do to solve this problem?

Comment: ... Install the i686 variant.